# Django GROUP BY strftime date format

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models, django-aggregation

I would like to do a SUM on rows in a database and group by date.

I am trying to run this SQL query using Django aggregates and annotations:

```
select strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time_stamp) as the_date, sum(numbers_data)
    from my_model
    group by the_date;
```

I tried the following:

```
data = My_Model.objects.values("strftime('%m/%d/%Y',
           time_stamp)").annotate(Sum("numbers_data")).order_by()
```

but it seems like you can only use column names in the values() function; it doesn't like the use of strftime().

How should I go about this?

Comment: Just found this:  http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10302

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for me:

```
select_data = {"d": """strftime('%%m/%%d/%%Y', time_stamp)"""}

data = My_Model.objects.extra(select=select_data).values('d').annotate(Sum("numbers_data")).order_by()
```

Took a bit to figure out I had to escape the % signs.

Comment: I got something like:
`Out[15]: <repr(<django.db.models.query.QuerySet at 0x749ef90>) failed: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1305, 'FUNCTION xxxxxx.strftime does not exist')>`
any ideas why?

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find out why it couldn't recognise strftime?

Answer (score 5):

As of v1.8, you can use [Func() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions).

For example, if you happen to be targeting AWS Redshift's date and time functions:

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

def TimezoneConvertedDateF(field_name, tz_name):
    tz_fn = Func(Value(tz_name), F(field_name), function='CONVERT_TIMEZONE')
    dt_fn = Func(tz_fn, function='TRUNC')
    return dt_fn
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
SomeDbModel.objects \
 .annotate(the_date=TimezoneConvertedDateF('some_timestamp_col_name',
                                           'America/New_York')) \
 .filter(the_date=...)
```

or like this:

```
SomeDbModel.objects \
 .annotate(the_date=TimezoneConvertedDateF('some_timestamp_col_name',
                                           'America/New_York')) \
 .values('the_date') \
 .annotate(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to just do this in the database, by running the following query against the database:

```
select date, sum(numbers_data) 
from my_model 
group by date;
```

If your answer is, the date is a datetime with non-zero hours, minutes, seconds, or milliseconds, my answer is to use a date function to truncate the datetime, but I can't tell you exactly what that is without knowing what RBDMS you're using.

Comment: Right now I am just using sqlite3 for proof of concept.  The "date" is indeed a datetime field.  I was using strftime() to truncate the datetime field to a date.  Is there something better for sqlite3?  What do you mean by "just do this in the database"?  Thanks!

Comment: I mean, just use whatever facility exisyts in Django to make a straight sql select.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about strftime, my solution below is using sql postgres trunc...

```
select_data = {"date": "date_trunc('day', creationtime)"}       
ttl = ReportWebclick.objects.using('cms')\
                    .extra(select=select_data)\
                    .filter(**filters)\
                    .values('date', 'tone_name', 'singer', 'parthner', 'price', 'period')\
                    .annotate(loadcount=Sum('loadcount'), buycount=Sum('buycount'), cancelcount=Sum('cancelcount'))\
                    .order_by('date', 'parthner')
```

-- equal to sql query execution:

```
select date_trunc('month', creationtime) as date, tone_name, sum(loadcount), sum(buycount), sum(cancelcount)
from webclickstat
group by tone_name, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution like this when my db is mysql:

```
select_data = {"date":"""FROM_UNIXTIME( action_time,'%%Y-%%m-%%d')"""} 
qs = ViewLogs.objects.filter().extra(select=select_data).values('mall_id', 'date').annotate(pv=Count('id'), uv=Count('visitor_id', distinct=True))
```

to use which function, you can read mysql datetime processor docs like    DATE_FORMAT,FROM_UNIXTIME...

Comment: Please format your code snippet so it is readable to others/OP